# Can't upload image to EC2 Instance with CollectionFS/GridFS ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, gridfs, collectionfs

I'm working on a simple **Meteor app** which manages profile pictures, **while working in local my project is working fine**.

But after deploying it on an AWS EC2 instance (With Meteor-Up), every works fine, except the image upload.

I'm using CollectionFS (`cfs:standard-packages, cfs:gridfs`).
Here's the code :

```
// Collection definition
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("original")]
});

Images.allow({
  'insert': function () {
    return true;
  },
  'update': function () {
    return true;
  },
  'download':function(){
    return true;
  }
});

// Event to upload the image
"click .js-validate"(event, instance){
  Images.insert(instance.file.get(), function (err, fileObj) {
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log("No error");
      console.log(err);
      Meteor.call('updatePP', fileObj._id, function(){
        Modal.hide("Modal_update_pp");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The security rules for my EC2 instance :

[image]

And here's the error showing when i execute the event which execute the `Images.insert` function.

[image]

The error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is showing.
I'm able to get the image id, but the image `isUploaded` function return `false` :

[image]

Why am i having this error and how can i solve this problem ? 
Is it due to my EC2 configuration or the code inside my Meteor Project ? Thanks !

Comment: For people wondering, i tried with Meteor-Files (ostrio:files) and it's working fine ! Still haven't find a solution for CollectionFS, but anyway, i'll switch to Meteor-Files and stop using CollectionFS.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest to switch to ostrio:files which is fully documented and up to date. GridFS is really old and buggy. You can then save your files securely to a S3 instance and keep your MongoDB size low.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will try to use it if nobody finds a solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi I think it would be better if you didn’t write the profile photos to a Mongo DB with so many options around. Profile photos have something particular to consider: the ratio. If somebody uploads a rectangular photo and you present it square/round, how do you avoid cutting off half the head? This is why you would need face detection and “weighting” of the photo in order to center a photo before presenting it. beside that you need web caching, you don’t want to call that photo from mongo every time you need to present it. Rather get it from somewhere else. How about Cloudinary?

Comment: I note your suggestion, but for the resizing, i'm already using CropperJS and it works like a charm. Thx

Comment: Perfect, so you only need the storage. The problem with GridFS is that I think nobody will be able to assist you because it is  ... old, as a package as well as a concept.